# set cursor at end of the text for text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My requirement is to place the cursor at the end of the text in a text box which already has text in it.How can i produce the functionality using Java Script/ css/ JQuery.

```html
<span>
  <input id="listInput" class="autocomplete-input singleselect-autocomplete-input" type="text" />
</span>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below function it works for me in chrome/IE/FF.

```js
 $("#inputtextboxID").on("focus", this.SetCaretAtEnd.bind());

function SetCaretAtEnd(){
var RefValue = $("#inputtextboxID")[0];
var RefValueLen = RefValue.value.length;
    // For IE Only
    if (document.selection) {
        // Set focus
        RefValue.focus();
        // Use IE Ranges
        var selectedText = document.selection.createRange();
        // Reset position to 0 & then set at end
        selectedText.moveStart('character', -RefValueLen);
        selectedText.moveStart('character', RefValueLen);
        selectedText.moveEnd('character', 0);
        selectedText.select();
    }
    else if (RefValue.selectionStart || RefValue.selectionStart == '0') {
        // Firefox/Chrome
        RefValue.selectionStart = RefValueLen;
        RefValue.selectionEnd = RefValueLen;
        RefValue.focus();
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selectionStart **and** selectionEnd properties of the textarea to the length of the current value.

Comment: can u please provide a code a perfect code for it in order to work in all browsers like chrome,IE,FF,safari